# If $\gcd(a,n)=1$ then there exist integers $x,y$ such that $0<|x|,|y|<\sqrt{n}$ and $ax\equiv y \pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> If $a$ is integer and $n$ is positive integer such that $\gcd(a,n)=1$  then there exist integers $x,y$ for which $0<|x|,|y|<\sqrt{n}$ and $ax\equiv y\pmod n$.

By Dirichlet's principle I could found that $|x|,|y|\le \sqrt n $ but how to rule out $|x|=\sqrt n $ or $|y|=\sqrt n$?

Comment: is modn modulus n?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pigeonhole principle. There are $2\lceil \sqrt n \rceil-2$ choices for each of $x,y$, so $(2\lceil \sqrt n \rceil-2)^2 \gt n$ ways to try to match them up.  At least one will match.

Comment: there are $([\sqrt n] +1 )^2 $ ways, not $(2[\sqrt n] +1 )^2 $ and then we will have $0<|x|,|y|\le \sqrt n$  and I have problems for case when $ |x|,|y|= \sqrt n$.

Comment: @user140378 The question doesn't specify that $x$ and $y$ are positive.

Comment: In fact, if $x,y$ must be positive it fails with $a=3,n=4$, where the only choice is $x=y=1$  It does specify $x,y \neq 0$, so I took off the $+1$

Comment: @RossMillikan Perhaps it should be $2\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor - 2$, since we are worried about the case where $n$ is a square.

Comment: @Slade:  You are right, but I get ceiling instead of floor.  Fixed.  Thanks

Comment: but what if $|x_i-x_j|=n$ ?

Comment: You can't have $|x_i-x_j|=n$ (unless $n=2$) because $2 \lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor \lt n$

Comment: Oh sorry I mean when $x_i-x_j=\sqrt n$

Comment: Then there is nothing special $\pmod n$.  What is there to worry about?

Comment: but in problem we must have $ |x|<n$, not $|x|\le n$

Comment: So if we take $n=9$, we can have $x,y=\pm 1,2$.  $a=1,2$ are easy, $a=4,x=2,y=-1$, which has $x-y=3=\sqrt n$.  No problem.  The other possibilities for $a$ work as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're assuming that $x$ and $y$ are positive, then the problem statement is false for $a=3$, $n=4$.

But the absolute value signs suggest that we should also consider negative integers.  This fixes the problem, because it gives us enough freedom to guarantee a pair $(x,y)$ in the appropriate range using the pigeonhole argument.